# read csv file using string from another df(pandas, python, dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is it possible to read csv file using string from another df?

normally, to read a csv file, i'd use the code as follow:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/file_name.csv")
```

however, i'd like to automate reading a csv file using string from another df:

```
df1_string = df1.iloc[0]['file_name']
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/df1_string.csv")
```

i got a FileNotFoundError when i tried the above code:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/Desktop/df1_string,csv' does not exist

kindly advices, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [python string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
df1_string = df1.iloc[0]['file_name']
df2 = pd.read_csv(f"C:/Users/Desktop/{df1_string }.csv")
```

Comment: thank you for the response, could you provide an example of how it works if  df1_string = apple

Comment: In that case it will create an empty dataframe with one column named as apple

Comment: i'm not sure whether i'm getting this right. but im trying to read(open) a cvs file in a folder.  which df1 goes thru a function to generate the name of the file to be opened. In this case, the name of the file is 'apple'. however, the code you provide seems to be creating a  new df instead.

Comment: Check the edited answer. is this what u want?

Comment: yeah, that's the one. sorry wasn't clear on my question. thanks